# Do I need to store PDB files from deterministic builds?

Tags: c#, roslyn

In general, it has always been recommended to save PDB outputs from builds to help debugging crashes, even for "release" code. This has always been because the PDB file has to match the executable and these could change between builds, even with identical source code.

However, since we now have deterministic builds in C#, is this as important? Even if the PDB file itself is not deterministic, if the executable is, I assume that I could just rebuild the code later and use the PDB generated that time to debug when needed?

Comment: Unless you've capture the whole build in a Docker container or something, I wouldn't be confident you'd be replicating it, determinism or not. All determinism gives you is the guarantee that if you use the same version of the compiler with the same configuration on the same source that you'll be getting the same output -- and that's nice, but those are still pretty big "if"s for when you need symbols way further down the line and aren't in the position to roll out a new binary.

Comment: I guess I hadn't quite appreciated what can still change the output of a deterministic build...good points and answers my questions well, thanks!